# What is the 'id' in officers layout_properties refrencing?

Tags: r, debugging, officer

What is the id in layout_properties? I'm not sure if the id is referring to the placeholder or something else. Here's an example:

```
                 master_name                                  name  type id                 ph_label                                                            ph
1  Figures Master - 20210903                                SP TOC title  2                  Title 1             <p:ph type="title" idx="10" hasCustomPrompt="1"/>
3  Figures Master - 20210903           F&LR - Figures Cover, 2 Col  body  4    Content Placeholder 
                                         <NA>
         offx      offy        cx        cy rotation fld_id fld_type
1   0.8400000 1.1878784 12.073192 0.4848491       NA   <NA>     <NA>
3   0.8399989 3.7499989  5.500000 3.1200000       NA   <NA>     <NA>
```

I'm asking because I'm looking for the 'rId' to use for my src to correct the error below. Mostly just curious though as I haven't been able to find this error online.

```
Error in external_img(material_shapes[stat_headers$directions$avg_lease_rate]) : 
src must be a string starting with 'rId' or an existing image filename
```

Edit:
As David mentioned for this error you have to make sure the whole path is specified with the correct file name being called. I fixed it to show the whole path and not just a portion. In addition, if there are multiple files being called through an if statement you will run into

```
Error in if .... the condition has length > 1
```

There are a lot of fixes if you search it up, but you would basically use if_else.

Comment: `material_shapes[stat_headers$directions$avg_lease_rate]`, what is the value of this? It should be a path to an image, officer will then replace it with the correct expected `rid`. 'rId' is set internaly, this is the relationship id of the image (and you should not dive into internals if you don't want to suffer ;))

Comment: you sir are amazing. material_shapes is pointing to a tableau repository that contains images to be used for a ppt. It's outside the scope of the question, but how can I make sure the images are replaced by the expecting 'id'? Is that through the ph_label? @DavidGohel

Comment: It will only work if you provide an image path as illustrated in `?external_img`. for the 2nd Q, I don't know, `external_img` works - if you don't think so, you can open an issue with a reproducible code that fail, we will fix.

Comment: you've given me a lot of ideas to try out, this has had me stumped for quite a bit. thanks! @DavidGohel